# How to edit a form that has class error in VFP

Tags: foxpro, ocx, visual-foxpro

I have a form that I would like to append so that it shows all the data in xml format but the form I need to append give me an error saying class not licensed for use I thought I had found the solution for this by manually adding the classes but for this from it dose not seem to have worked can any one advise how i might locate the class the form is looking for or is there a work around I can use I just want ad one line to complete this code  `REPLACE photo_ref WITH property.photo_ref` so that populates all of the XML elements with data from the database

Comment: the error I am getting with ctmeter.ocx is that when I try to modify progress.scx I get OLE error class is not licensed for use any help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is that ctmeter.ocx is a commercial third-party control from DBI Technologies. Because you don't have a developer licence for it, you can run compiled applications that use it but you can't edit any form or form class that contains it using Visual FoxPro.

So what you need to do is visit DBI Technologies on the web and investigate a developer licence for it.

Comment: Thank you Alan B for confirming my suspicions, I have just looked at the developers license and its almost the price of the program I bought

Comment: I think they regard their ActiveX stuff as sort of legacy, so I would contact them and ask if they will cut you a deal for just that one control.

Comment: Cheers Alan B I'll try that

Comment: Alan B Could I create a Form to replace the form without ctmeter.ocx with the same name as I believe that this is only a Graphic of a progress bar that I do not really need

Comment: sorry Alan B I am trying to think of solutions to this problem, I thought of using hex edit to edit the .sct

Comment: Well, you don't need to use a hex editor ... the SCX file is just a DBF file with a different extension, so you can open with Visual FoxPro as you would a DBF, and have a look at the contents. The method code and everything is available in memo fields.